# Register a component to an existing Vue.js instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to Vue.js.

I want to register a local component as described over here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration

The only issue is that I need to register a component to an **existing** Vue instance not while creating a new instance something like:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
    
app.component({
    'my-component': {
         template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
    }
});
```

I have tried Vue.extend for that, but it is not working.

**Edit:**

Why I need this:

I'm creating a 3rd party package which will have that component. The framework on which this package is going to be installed will already have Vue.js included and a Vue instance. So if I include my package's JS before framework's JS, then it will give me Vue is undefined and if I include my package's JS after framework's JS, then it will give me component error as it has to be registered before the Vue instantiation.

Comment: resolved this ?

Answer (score 3):

Global components should be declared before new instance construct.

```js
Vue.component('my-component-a', {
  template: '<div>A custom component A!</div>'
});

Vue.component('my-component-b', {
  template: '<div>A custom component B!</div>'
});

const app1 = new Vue({
    el: '#app1',
    template: '<div><my-component-a /><my-component-b /><my-component-c /></div>',
    components: {
      MyComponentC: {
        template: '<div>A custom component C!</div>'
      }
    }
});

const app2 = new Vue({
    el: '#app2',
    template: '<div><my-component-b /><my-component-a /><my-component-c /></div>'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app1"></div>
<div id="app2"></div>
```

You don't have access to the C component from within your app2

Answer (score 2):

You can't add components to an instance like that. All you can do it adding them to the Vue constructor like usual:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

See a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/kb9pbecq/

Comment: Yes, what's with it? You obviously can't render a component before you have added it.

Comment: Also about passed parameters. Need string and object, not just object. Anyway, I glad to meet you here)

Answer (score 0):

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'my-component': {template: '<div>Text in component</div>'}
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can not register a component to a existing Vue instance while it was already rendered.But you can register a component before the Vue instance mounted into the dom element.

```
// local component
var child = {
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
}

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   components: {
     Child: child
  }
})
```

or

```
// global component
Vue.component({
 'child': {
   template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
 } })
```

Define the component first and then implement it.